# detecting 32 bit integer overflow

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a simple method that basically reverses the signed integer. This function works till the integer is under or equal to 32 bit.
for example :-

```
input = 321
output = 123

input = -321
output = -123

input = 1534236469
output = 9646324351    //this value is wrong. 

expected output = 0
```

I want to detect the integer overflow and return 0 in that case.
Below is the code for the function

```
    int reverse(int x) {
    int number = x;
    bool negative = false;
    if(number<0){
        negative = true;
        number *= -1;
    }

    int reversed = 0;
    while (number != 0){
        int reminder = number % 10;
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + reminder;
        number /= 10;
    }
    if(negative){
        reversed *= -1;
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

Furthermore, if I change the input and output into signed long I get the required output but I want to detect the integer overflow and return 0.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through this algorithm of yours, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables at each step, what observations did you make? The answer to your question is: learn how to use a debugger. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: no, the answer is not that. He wants to **detect** when overflow occurs. He needs an algorithm which can do it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thanks. I checked through the debugger. the overflow is happening in multiplication. would be helpful to know if there is an easy way to detect that a number will possibly go through an overflow in case of an arithmetic operation.

Comment: You need to check `reversed` before the multiplication. If it is bigger than INT_MAX/10, then it will overflow. And maybe you need other checks too.

Comment: The working of your code assumes the value being reversed AND the reversed value can both be represented in a 32-bit integral type.   The value that is "wrong" cannot be represented in a 32-bit type.   You'll need to check for potential overflow BEFORE multiplying by 10 and before adding the "reminder".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you multiply `reversed` by 10, just check to make sure it's small enough to multiply by 10.

Similarly, before you add `remainder`, check to make sure it's small enough to add `remainder`.

There's a clever trick you can use for the addition, but at your level you probably shouldn't:

```
if ((reversed += remainder) < remainder) {
    //overflow
}
```

Note that the trick only works if both `reversed` and `remainder` are unsigned.

Comment: This is only guaranteed to work if `reversed` is an unsigned variable, you should mention it.

Comment: Still not OK. It has to be unsigned. Signed overflow is UB, no matter if it overflows positively or negatively.

Comment: @geza, that's true and I hate it.

Answer (score 2):

This hint might help you complete your assignment:

You are only going to get integer overflow if your final number is 10 digits long and the first digit ends up being above or equal to 2.

Which means that you are going to get integer overflow if your original number is also 10 digits long and the last digit is 2 or above.